# Read XML file using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have to read **an XML file using jQuery**, but I don't know **how to start it**.

The HTML file is located on my localhost.

This is what I have tried.
I have two problems.

1. I searched and tried to apply what I have read on how to read an XML file using jQuery
2. I don't know the problem, because the try and catch which is supposed to give me a hint of something what I have done wrong doesn't give me a error message or a hint.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   try {
       $("button").click(function(){
           var xml = $.parseXML("C:\Users\askquestion\Desktop\1.xml"),
           alert($xml);
       });
   }
   catch(err) {
       alert(err.message);
   } });
   ```

I'm trying to figure out how to make this code works, but why does it give me the output of "null"?

But the 1.xml is properly located

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "1.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
        //var root = $(xmlDoc).find("root");
        alert(xmlDoc);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel>  </rss>",
        xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
        $xml = $(xmlDoc),
        $title = $xml.find("title");

    // Append "RSS Title" to #someElement
    $("#someElement").append( $title.text());

    // Change the title to "XML Title"
    $title.text( "XML Title" );

    // Append "XML Title" to #anotherElement
    $( "#anotherElement").append( $title.text());
</script>
```

Here is the jQuery site path:

[Jquery.parseXML()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Comment: i updated my question. please see my code above. why it doesn't give me a output. its output is "null"

Comment: you sure the url is correct ? try to write the error in catch. like error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                } and check it returns data.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$.ajax` API to retrieve the XML using its web path on your server, not its hard drive path:

```
$.get('path/to/somefile.xml', function(xmlDoc){
      var $xml = $(xmlDoc);

      // Iterate the same you would with HTML
      $xml.find('nodeName').each(function(){
          var txt = $(this).find('childNodeName').text();
          console.log(txt);
      });
},'xml')
```

Comment: i updated my question. please see my code above. why it doesn't give me a output. its output is "null"

Comment: what does the xml look like? Don't use alert to debug, use console logging.